# Popup message box in c#

Tags: asp.net, messagebox, webusercontrol

I'm looking for a custom user control similar to http://www.how-to-asp.net/messagebox-control-aspnet/ but having the ability to be displayed as a popup. The message box should have the capability of being invoked from code behind in asp.net 4 with event hooks to bind the "ok" and "cancel" button.

I'm familiar with Ajax Toolkit and JQuery.

A reference and or sample in a similar direction would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, it's usually a sign of a bad design if you want to open something on the client side from the server side code behind. Are you sure that's what you need?

But assuming you do, you can use the [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) from the Ajax Control Tookit. It can be opened from client or server side. Here's a sample:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="LinkButton1" ClientIdMode="Static"
    PopupControlID="Panel1" />
```

The PopupControlID should be the ID of a panel that you want to appear as a popup. You can put buttons on that panel if you need to. From the code behind, it's as simple as this...

```
MPE.Show();
```

To show it from JavaScript (assuming jQuery), make sure you set the ClientIdMode to Static, then call it...

```
$('#MPE').show();
```

Comment: This works on my side as well as long as I don't put the asp.panel piece in a user control i.e. ascx file. If the panel is in the aspx page and I use and ModalPopupExtender it displays the pop-up fine.

I need the ability to use the popup to be fired from client side e.g. when a user hits a delete button on grid, to give a warning that the row will be permanently deleted. Similarly need to fire it from code, when the post back operation is done i.e. giving a confirmation to the user that processing went all ok.

Comment: You can put it in an ASCX user control. You just have to expose it as a property. `public ModalPopupExtender ThePopup {get; private set}` should be sufficient on your .ascx.cs code behind, then from your .aspx.cs code behind you could do `MyUserControl.ThePopup.Show()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). They have great examples. I use the dialog all the time.

You can view their source and here is an example of one.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
```

You are able to customize this anyway you want. The link will show you how to do this.

EDIT: Since you want to open it in the behind code, I'll show you my jQuery and how I call it in the behind code. I use this to send emails.

```
function sendEmail() {
    $("#email").dialog({
       modal: true,
       width: 700,
       buttons: {
          "Send": function () {
             var btn = document.getElementById("<%=lbSend.ClientID %>");
             if (btn) btn.click();
             $(this).dialog("close");
           },
           Cancel: function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
      );
      jQuery("#email").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    };
```

Then in the behind code.

```
 protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //this calls the jQuery function.
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "sendEmail();", true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void Message(String msg)
    {
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += msg;
        script += "');";
        script += "window.location = '";
        script += "'; }";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
```